# how to create react native drawer using tailwind according to this ui

Tags: drawerlayout, slidingdrawer, react-navigation-drawer, android-drawer

Guys I am stuck here and I cant understand what to do. I have created an drawer menu in react native using nativewind, here's the code and image

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  Pressable,
  Animated,
  StyleSheet,
  Touchable,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from "react-native";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import {
  Ionicons,
  MaterialCommunityIcons,
  AntDesign,
  EvilIcons,
  Entypo,
  Feather,
} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Tab, TabView } from "@rneui/themed";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// Components
import Divider from "../Components/Divider";
import IndividualCard from "../Components/IndividualCard";
import DebateCard from "../Components/DebateCard";
import Votes from "../Components/Votes";
import PollsCard from "../Components/PollsCard";

const ClubPageScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [showContent1, setShowContent1] = useState(true);
  const [showContent2, setShowContent2] = useState(false);

  const handleButton1Click = () => {
    setShowContent1(true);
    setShowContent2(false);
  };

  const handleButton2Click = () => {
    setShowContent1(false);
    setShowContent2(true);
  };

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  **const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const drawerWidth = 250; // Width of the drawer
  const animationDuration = 300; // Animation duration in milliseconds

  const drawerAnimation = new Animated.Value(isOpen ? drawerWidth : 0);

  const toggleDrawer = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
    Animated.timing(drawerAnimation, {
      toValue: isOpen ? 0 : drawerWidth,
      duration: animationDuration,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const drawerStyles = {
    transform: [{ translateX: drawerAnimation }],
  };**
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      **{isOpen && (
        <View className="">
          <Animated.View className="" pointerEvents={isOpen ? "auto" : "none"}>
            <Pressable className="absolute inset-0">
              <Text>close</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </Animated.View>

          <Animated.View className="h-full w-72 bg-white">
            <Text className="tex-center tex-2xl mt-10 p-5">
              I am inside the drawer
            </Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      )}**
      <View className="bg-[#262626] py-4 px-4">
        <View className="flex-row justify-between">
          <View className=" flex-row items-center gap-x-3">
            **<Pressable className="" onPress={toggleDrawer}>
              <Feather name="menu" size={30} color="white" />
            </Pressable>**
            <Text className="text-white text-xl font-medium">
              Aspirant Club{" "}
              <Entypo name="chevron-down" size={20} color="white" />
            </Text>
          </View>

          <Pressable
            className="text-white text-xl my-auto"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("GeneralChatScreen")}
          >
            <Image
              source={require("../app/assets/icons/chat-white.png")}
              className="w-6 h-6"
            />
          </Pressable>
        </View>

        <Tab
          value={index}
          onChange={(e) => setIndex(e)}
          indicatorStyle={{
            backgroundColor: "white",
            height: 2,
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Item TouchableComponent={TouchableWithoutFeedback}>
            <Text className="text-white text-lg mt-7">My Work</Text>
          </Tab.Item>

          <Tab.Item TouchableComponent={TouchableWithoutFeedback}>
            <Text className="text-white text-lg mt-7">
              Club's Feed &nbsp;
              <View className="p-1 h-1 bg-red-700 rounded-full -translate-y-3 -translate-x-2"></View>
            </Text>
          </Tab.Item>
        </Tab>
      </View>

      <View>
        {showContent1 && <MyWork navigation={navigation} />}
        {showContent2 && (
          <ScrollView>
            {/* Discussions */}
            <View className="bg-white px-4 py-5">
              <View className="flex flex-row justify-start gap-5">
                <View className=" bg-indigo-100/50 rounded-full px-3 py-1">
                  <Text className="text-indigo-600 font-medium">
                    Discussions
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View className=" bg-indigo-100/50 rounded-full px-3 py-1">
                  <Text>Debates</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>

            {/* Individual Cards */}
            <IndividualCard
              content={{
                title:
                  "Indian education system: A discussion on edu-system of our India",
                description:
                  "From Access to Quality: Addressing the Challenges and Opportunities. Participate in",
                image: "../app/assets/discussion-img.png",
              }}
            />

            {/* Polling Cards */}
            <PollsCard
              title={"that are the best ways to crack SSC 'CGL' exam?"}
            />
            <DebateCard
              content={{
                title: "that are the best ways to crack SSC 'CGL' exam?",
                description:
                  "Any student who has given this exam earlier, please share your priceless experience to...",
              }}
            />
            {/* Votes  */}
            <Votes />
          </ScrollView>
        )}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ClubPageScreen;

const MyWork = ({ navigation }) => (
  <View className="my-7">
    <View className="flex-row justify-between px-5 pb-5">
      <Text className="font-medium text-lg">Today's task</Text>
      <Text className="text-indigo-700 text-lg">+ Add Task</Text>
    </View>

    <ScrollView className="">
      <View className="bg-gray-200 rounded-t-3xl p-10 pb-96">
        <NoTaskCard
          title={"No task available for today!"}
          navigation={navigation}
        />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
        <TaskCard date={""} time={""} subject={""} chapter={""} question={""} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);

const NoTaskCard = ({ title, navigation }) => (
  <View className="bg-white p-5 rounded-xl justify-center items-center gap-y-3 py-10">
    <Text className="text-gray-400 text-xl">{title}</Text>
    <Pressable
      className="bg-indigo-700 p-3 px-5 rounded-xl"
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("TaskForm")}
    >
      <Text className="text-white text-lg">Create task</Text>
    </Pressable>
  </View>
);

const TaskCard = ({ date, time, chapter, question, subject, navigation }) => (
  <View className="bg-white p-5 rounded-lg py-3 mt-2">
    <View className="flex-row justify-between">
      <View className="flex-row items-center gap-x-1">
        <Image
          source={require("../app/assets/icons/calendar.png")}
          className="w-5 h-5"
        />
        <Text>03 Feb 2023</Text>
        <Text>@ 3Pm</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Image
          source={require("../app/assets/icons/edit.png")}
          className="w-7 h-7"
        />
      </View>
    </View>
    <Divider />
    <View className="flex-row mt-3 gap-x-3">
      <Text className="text-[15px]">Subject :</Text>
      <Text className="text-gray-600">Modern History</Text>
    </View>
    <View className="flex-row mt-3 gap-x-3">
      <Text className="text-[15px]">Chapter :</Text>
      <Text className="text-gray-600 pr-16">
        Portuguese in India, Dutch in India, Danes in India, The English, The
        French, more
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View className="flex-row mt-3 gap-x-3">
      <Text className="text-[15px]">Questions :</Text>
      <Text className="text-gray-600">Total 45 questions</Text>
    </View>
    <View className="bg-indigo-700 p-2 mt-3 rounded-xl">
      <Text className="text-white text-lg text-center">Complete Task</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

[Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W4S3.png) 
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9fv0.png)

I have made the particular code bold on here which needs focus.
So the problem is I need to make it something like this but I cannot understand how to do so.

[Desired ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDpFI.png)

Can someone help me make this type of drawer design ?(the design of the content of the drawer is not required just the design of the outer UI)

I tried referring youtube videos but didn't helped me